# Как правильно хранить данные в COOKIE?

Tags: php, cookie

Если хранить в куках пароли, логины или прочие какие-то данные, то их можно легко подделать, тогда в чем смысл кук? Я чего-то не пониманию, видимо. Как в них правильно хранить данные, чтобы их не подделали?

Comment: Сессии ваше все.

Answer (score 2):

Смысл в `куках` - хранение информации после закрытия браузера (вкладки). К примеру, информацию о товарах, добавленных в корзину. Или, например, плейлист, который ты слушал вчера.

В куках не хранят пароли, детали платежей и прочую важную информацию. Как максимум "идишник", по которому уже на стороне сервера "выдернеться" нужная информация из базы (при совпадении ещё множества факторов, таких как ip, useragent, timezone, hardware id и т.д.).

А ещё с помощью `кук` можно передавать данные между владками одного сайта, в реальном времени, но сейчас для этого больше используют `localStorage`.

Comment: тогда для проверки админа или прочих серьезных проверок на сайте, данные заносятся в сессии??

Comment: в сессиях так же??

Comment: А где хранят такие данные тогда? Для проверки админа не админа... В сессиях??

Comment: В куках хранится идентификатор сессии, но данные хранятся на сервере. То есть мы передаем ID сессии на сервер, он берет из базы данные, у себя делает то что нужно и возвращает клиенту)